# ControlID changes each time a window is launched

Tags: autoit

Consider this [AutoIt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt) code:

```
WinActivate("Test Window")

Sleep(5000)

ControlClick("Test Window", "", 197128)
```

There is a button in the window I am testing. I have written a simple script to click on the button using [ControlClick](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlClick.htm). I use controlID to identify and click on the button (I use AutoIt window Info to get the controlID). The script works. The problem is that the control ID changes each time the test window is launched. As a result, the script does not simulate a button click each time a new instance of the window is launched. How can I make controlclick work as expected every time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For controls that have dynamic control Ids, the best is to use advanced detection.

As it can be seen in the Help File:

> A special description can be used as the controlID parameter used in most of the
>   Control...() functions. This description can be used to identify a control by the
>   following properties:

For example,

```
ControlSend("Untitled - Notepad", "", "[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:1]", "This is some text")
```

Or

```
ControlClick("My Window", "", "[CLASS:Button; TEXT:Finish; INSTANCE:2]")
```

Don't forget to set:

```
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 4) ;1=start, 2=subStr, 3=exact, 4=advanced, -1 to -4=Nocase
```

Comment: You can also use `""` for both the `$title` and `$text` to always use the active window.

Comment: @Chrono that's completely off topic since we are talking about getting the control handle and not the window handle.
Anyway, if you aren't coding directly for any active window, you should avoid using the control..() functions in the way you suggested since its unreliable.

Comment: How is that off topic? I'm just saying you can also use `ControlClick("", "", "[CLASS:Button; TEXT:Finish; INSTANCE:2]")`.